# Popular input com dados de uma mesma tabela via dropdown

Tags: php, dropdown, input

Eu tenho um *select* que puxa o nome de um produto.

Quero que ao selecionar o nome do produto via *dropdown* ela preencha automaticamente uma *input* com código do respectivo produto. A informação está em uma única tabela, no caso `id, id_produto, nome ,serial, log`.

Eu consigo puxar os dados para o *dropdown* mas não sei como vincular um *input* com o `id_produto`.

Espero ter conseguido passar minha dúvida.

```
<select name="produto" id="produto">
<?php $sql = mysql_query("select * from produto");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       print '<option value="'.$row['nome'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select><br/>
```

Comment: Seu código não tem JS?

Comment: tem sim, eu até consigo vincular dados de outras tabelas, só não sei como fazer isso puxando da mesma de onde eu já fiz o _select_ do "**nome**".

Comment: Você quer que quando o select seja escolhido o ID preencha um campo input? É isso?

Comment: quero que quando eu selecione o nome do produto, automaticamente ele preencha um input com o código interno do produto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="inputdesejado">
<select name="produto" id="produto">
<!-- Isso ira evitar que dispare o change quando carregar. -->
<option value="" disable>Escolha um produto:</option>
<?php $sql = mysql_query("select * from produto");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       print '<option value="'.$row['id_produto'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select><br/>
```

E faça um javascript com o seguinte código:

```
$("#produto").change(function(){
  $("#inputdesejado").val() = $(this).val();
})'
```

Comment: Tenho que criar um input com "#inputdesejado"?

Comment: @Ronny Amarante, respondeu antes de mim :) Jogue o exemplo no jsfiddle para eu remover minha resposta

Comment: @Thiago, ali você da o ID do seu input. Crie um `<input type="hidden" id="nomedesejado">` esse nome vc passa ali no jQuery...

Comment: @PapaCharlie, pode deixar, postei rapidinho apenas para ele ter noção do código, o seu esta explicando melhor...

Comment: Ainda não consigo dar print no id_produto, o _input_ fica em branco mas começo a intender a lógico, agradeço muito vocês 2.

Comment: @Thiago, meu exemplo mostra todos elementos necessários, basta executar e modelar como a resposta do Ronny Amarante

Comment: @Thiago, você tem o jQuery no seu projeto? Caso sim, verifique as devidas identificações dos seletores.

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado, vocês dois não tem ideia do quanto me ajudaram!

Comment: Tenho outra dúvida, quando envio os dados para o banco, o campo **produto** e **id_produto** grava a mesma informação, no caso sempre grava o id_produto em ambos os campos, como se resolve isso?

Comment: @Thiago, faça outra pergunta para especificar melhor o caso, não estou conseguindo imaginar a situação sem ver o código e os outros detalhes...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#produto').change(function() {
        $('#recebe').val( $( this ).val() );
    });
});
</script>

<select name="produto" id="produto">
    <option value="ID-A">a</option>
    <option value="ID-B">b</option>
    <option value="ID-B">c</option>
</select>

<input id="recebe" />
```

Pode ver online aqui no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e12hgvfd/).